# Solving the quadratic in the Fast Iterative Method

Tags: quadratic-programming

The [Fast Iterative Method](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220411914_A_Fast_Iterative_Method_for_Eikonal_Equations) is a way of solving the Eikonal Equation on a discrete grid, similar to the Fast Marching Method discussed in [another question here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/solving-the-quadratic-in-the-fast-marching-method).

The paper describes the overall algorithm, as well as providing a method for solving the quadratic, as follows:

> **SolveQuadratic(a, b, c, f)**
>
> *Returns the value $u = Ux$ that solves $g(U, x) = 0$, where $a ≤ b ≤ c$*
>
> ```
> u ← c + 1/f
> if u ≤ b return (u)
> u ← (b + c + sqrt(−b^2 − c^2 + 2bc + 2/f^2))/2
> if u ≤ a return (u)
> u ← (2(a + b + c) + sqrt(4(a + b + c)^2 − 12(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 − 1/f^2)))/6
> return (u)
> ```

That's easy enough to implement, as is the rest of the FIM algorithm. However, I'm unclear what the inputs $a, b, c$ are in the context of the problem (I do understand how to get $f$, though, I think). They are descried as "values $a, b, c$ of upwind
neighbors in the cardinal directions of the grid".

I only need to solve in a 2-dimensional grid, so I believe I only need $f$ plus two inputs, and would drop the second test-and-recalculate step above, but I still need $b, c$.

I should note that I'm not a strong maths person; I have a BSc in Comp. Sci. but my maths skills are first-year / freshman level at best, and rusty...

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have a 6-connected neighbourhood. Say a,b,c,d,e,f are the neighbour values. And (a,e) are in x direction, (b,e) are in y direction and (c,f) are in z direction. As your wavefront never changes the sign of its speed, the upwind-neighbourhood are those points with smaller values, that is a